# Is there a way I can inner join two lists of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, join, python-3.7

I am wanting to know if there is a way I can join these two lists of dictionary as an inner join on the "id" key. I am new to Python and can't wrap my head on how to do this. The two lists must have the same number of columns, but the number of rows may be arbitrary. It is assumed that the first "column" in each list is the key to be joining on.

```
employees = [{"id": 1, "name": "Steve"},
             {"id": 2, "name": "Craig"},
             {"id": 3, "name": "James"},
             {"id": 10,"name": "Joseph"}]
sports =    [{"id": 1, "sport": "Basketball"},
             {"id": 1, "sport": "Tennis"},
             {"id": 2, "sport": "Basketball"},
             {"id": 3, "sport": "Basketball"},]

# I need to return a new list of dicts that will have values as the following: 
# innerJoined = [{"id": 1, "name": "Steve", "sport": "Basketball"},
#                {"id": 1, "name": "Steve", "sport": "Tennis"},
#                {"id": 2, "name": "Craig", "sport": "Basketball"},
#                {"id": 3, "name": "James", "sport": "Basketball"}]
#
```

Comment: If you want a database, you probably should use a database. I assume you have a basic understanding of them, given the terms you use to describe the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I understand how to do it in a database, but the question requires us to do this without using databases. Only in python with no external libraries imported.

Comment: "the question requires us to do this without using databases"—is this homework? A hiring challenge? A programming test?

Comment: "It is assumed that the first "column" in each list is the key to be joining on"—there isn't a "first column" in many versions of Python. Before Python 3.7 dicts were unordered and did not preserve insertion order.

Comment: @Chris it is a practice question for a class

Comment: @Chris sorry, I'm still very new to python. But I hope you understand what I mean when I say that. The first key in each of the dict tuples is what I am trying to say.

Comment: @mamba-mentality24, my point is that Python might literally not be able to give you back the dicts in the same order. E.g., if I type `{"foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3, "quux": 4}` into Python 2.7 I get back `{'baz': 3, 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'quux': 4}`. The key / value pairs are unordered. Even in Python 3.7+ I don't think there's a way to index into a dict to get its "first" key and value. You'd have to provide the name of the key to use. If you're using a specific version of Python, please make sure to use an appropriate tag. The language's behaviour officially changed with Python 3.7.

Comment: The question would be easy if the joins key was defined as "id" rather than "first key" for the reason stated above. "sports" has two items with id=1. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You could always try to iterate over the first list and then for each row take the "id" key and see how many other items it matches in the 2nd list (using a 2nd nested for loop). For every match, you concatenate the dict in first list with the matching dict in 2nd list and append them to a results list. This is of course an O(n^2) solution.

To improve on that if you know that the two lists will always be sorted by "id", then you can keep a counter which keeps track of how far you have explored the 2nd list and then start the next run of the 2nd nested for loop from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pythonic way:

Code:

```
employees = [{"id": 1, "name": "Steve"},
             {"id": 2, "name": "Craig"},
             {"id": 3, "name": "James"},
             {"id": 10,"name": "Joseph"}]
sports =    [{"id": 1, "sport": "Basketball"},
             {"id": 1, "sport": "Tennis"},
             {"id": 2, "sport": "Basketball"},
             {"id": 3, "sport": "Basketball"},]

innerJoined = sports.copy()
for ind, s in enumerate(innerJoined):
    innerJoined[ind]['name'] = [e['name'] for e in employees if e['id'] == s['id']][0]
print(innerJoined)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'sport': 'Basketball', 'name': 'Steve'}, 
{'id': 1, 'sport': 'Tennis', 'name': 'Steve'}, 
{'id': 2, 'sport': 'Basketball', 'name': 'Craig'}, 
{'id': 3, 'sport': 'Basketball', 'name': 'James'}]
```